# check version numbers using #if ... #endif

Tags: c

How can I check for version >= a set version, e.g. 2.3.4.17 if I have the following definitions (each one may have 1-2 digits)?

```
#define VERSION_NUM_MAJOR 1
#define VERSION_NUM_MINOR 0
#define VERSION_NUM_SERVPACK 0
#define VERSION_NUM_BUILD 10
```

If I'd have the following definition ...

```
#define VERSION_NUM 1000010
```

... it would be as easy as ...

```
#if VERSION_NUM > 2030417
```

but unfortunately, the legacy SDKs don't provide it and I need it for conditional compiling ("#if ... #endif").

I could do it like this, but this looks much to complicated:

```
#if (VERSION_NUM_MAJOR > 2) || ((VERSION_NUM_MAJOR == 2) && ((VERSION_NUM_MINOR > 3) || ((VERSION_NUM_MINOR == 3) && ((VERSION_NUM_SERVPACK > 4) || ((VERSION_NUM_SERVPACK == 4) && (VERSION_NUM_BUILD >= 17))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
#define VERSION_MIN(a,b,c,d) (VERSION_NUM_MAJOR>a)||((VERSION_NUM_MAJOR==a)&&((VERSION_NUM_MINOR>b)||((VERSION_NUM_MINOR==b)&&((VERSION_NUM_SERVPACK>c)||((VERSION_NUM_SERVPACK==c)&&(VERSION_NUM_BUILD>=d))))))
#if VERSION_MIN(2,3,4,17)
#endif
```